# I want alphabet strip (like in addressBook) on UITableViewControler 

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want an alphabet strip (like in addressBook) on UITableViewController.  Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the TableView delegate method

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

}
```

Cheers

Comment: aditya i stucked on previous problem plz check it if you know its answer

Comment: Dude... i will surely have a look but that might not happen today.. but rest assured i will...

Comment: @Aditya I solved the issue related to my previous Questions thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct answer is

```
- (NSArray *) sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
}
```

just for the record!

Apple documentation:
**Return Value**
An array of strings that serve as the title of sections in the table view and appear in the index list on the right side of the table view. The table view must be in the plain style (UITableViewStylePlain). For example, for an alphabetized list, you could return an array containing strings “A” through “Z”.